# Image Resampling in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, resampling

I've wrote below code for landsat and sentinel mosaicing, however I don't know how can I resample sentinel-2 pixel size to landsat-8 data? Could anyone guide me please?

code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/e65292e8cda25e846d2a9889a91a3b45

```
Map.centerObject(table)

var sen2mosaic = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
.filterDate('2018-01-01','2019-01-01')
.filterBounds(table)
.map(function(img){
  var bands = img.select('B[3-4]','B8')
  .multiply(0.0001).clip(table)
   return bands
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end'])

})
.min();

Map.addLayer(sen2mosaic,[],'sen2mosaic',false)


var lan8mosaic = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1')
.filterDate('2018-01-01','2019-01-01')
.filterBounds(table)
.map(function(img){
  var bands = img.select('B[3-5]')
  .multiply(0.0001).clip(table)
  return bands
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end'])

})
.min();

Map.addLayer(lan8mosaic,[],'lan8mosaic',false)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [resampling docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/resample) on the Earth Engine Guides, you can reduce resolution using the `ee.Image.reproject()` function. Check out the link for more on what's going on under the hood, and make note of the warnings they list there.

```
var myCounty = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/Counties')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME', 'Kalawao'));
var table = myCounty;

Map.centerObject(table);

var sen2mosaic = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
.filterDate('2018-01-01','2019-01-01')
.filterBounds(table)
.map(function(img){
  var bands = img.select('B[3-4]','B8')
  .multiply(0.0001).clip(table);
   return bands
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);

})
.min();
print("sen2mosaic", sen2mosaic);


var lan8mosaic = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1')
.filterDate('2018-01-01','2019-01-01')
.filterBounds(table)
.map(function(img){
  var bands = img.select('B[3-5]')
  .multiply(0.0001).clip(table);
  return bands
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);

})
.min();
print("lan8mosaic", lan8mosaic);

// Using code from earthEngine docs:
// Get LS8 projection
var ls8Projection = lan8mosaic.projection();
// Resample Sentinel data
var sentinelMean = sen2mosaic
    .reproject({
      crs: ls8Projection,
      scale: 30
    });

print("sentinelMean",sentinelMean);


// Display the aggregated, reprojected data.
Map.addLayer(lan8mosaic.visualize({bands:["B3","B4","B5"], min:0, max:1}),[],'lan8 NDVI');
Map.addLayer(sen2mosaic.normalizedDifference({bandNames:["B8","B4"]}), {min:0, max:1},'sen2 NDVI');
Map.addLayer(sentinelMean.normalizedDifference({bandNames:["B8","B4"]}), {min:0, max:1}, 'Sentinel NDVI at LS8 scale');
```